# Javascript Range Computation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have here an html page with a script, how can i get the total of this condition? The minimum charge is 15 for the range 1-1000 of the input.The succeeding range will be the input value +1.5% of the maximum range. Example if I input 2300 which falls to the 2000-2500 range, the total will be 2338 which comes to the 1.5% of its Max range.

```
$('#padala-pera').keyup(function() {
  let iv = +$(this).val();
  let num;
  if (iv <= 1000) num = 15;
  else {
    let times = Math.ceil(iv / 500);

    if (times % 2 == 0) {
      num = 15 + Math.ceil((iv - 1000) / 500) * 8;
    } else {
      num = 15 + Math.ceil((iv - 1000) / 500) * 7;
    }

    let result = iv + num;
    $('#padala-result').text(`₱${Math.ceil(result)}`);
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='padala-pera' />
<div id='padala-result'></div>
```

to make things clear, here are the range and amount of charge to be compute.
[image]

Comment: So what exactly is the error you are encountering with your attempts to solve this? What is the specific problem you need help with?

Comment: My result is always exceeds or less than the total amount. i didnt know how to properly execute the javascript codes sir.

Comment: Your code is overly complicated, this should do the trick: `let total = val + Math.ceil((Math.ceil(val / 500.0) * 500) * 0.015)`  where `val` is your input value (`iv` in your code) https://jsfiddle.net/4wfxv3yq/1/  This assumes your "cash-in/-out" value has been rounded rather than the 1.5% (2300 would be 2337.50 for 1.5).   There's probably some edge cases which is why you've got those `times % 2 == 0` but I couldn't really see what they were for / why they were needed.

Comment: @freedomn-m just need a `Math.max(15, x)` around that too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah, there's no 0-500 range.  I knew there'd be some dodgy case in the table, but scanned down and they all seemed to be +500 from the last one.   You can bump up the first value to 500.01 if it's less than 500.01 so that it hits the 1000 range:  `val + Math.ceil((Math.ceil(Math.max(500.01, val) / 500.0) * 500) * 0.015)`  or wrap the whole `+ calc` in Math.max to give a minimum cash-in/-out if preferred / clearer.

Comment: hello sir thanks for answering my questions, i am having trouble in displaying the code that you have given. is this correct? im sorry for a newbie question i am not that familiar with this language https://jsfiddle.net/sodium05/46rcbfk9/55/

Comment: Couple of typos - you mised the `val = $(this).val()` and tried to ouput `result` instead of `total` - along with an extra `}` - always check the console for errors.   https://jsfiddle.net/dhq2451v/  You're also missing the edge case for 0-500 as highlighted by @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: thank you very much sir im glad that it worked perfectly now. If added an if for the minimum charge  :)  https://jsfiddle.net/sodium05/46rcbfk9/60/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be reduced to a single line calculation:

```
let val = +$(this).val();
let total = val + Math.ceil((Math.ceil(Math.max(500.01, val) / 500.0) * 500) * 0.015)
```

Breakdown:

- `+$(this).val()` ensure val is a number
- `Math.max(500.01, val)` there's no case for 0-500, so when calculating the `1.5%` bump up to the 1000 max range
- `Math.ceil(Math.max(500.01, val) / 500.0) * 500` round up to the nearest 500
- `* 0.015` add 1.5%  `(1.5 / 100)` (of the nearest 500)
- `val + ...` add the original value back on

```js
$('#padala-pera').keyup(function() {
 let val = +$(this).val();
 let total = val + Math.ceil((Math.ceil(Math.max(500.01, val) / 500.0) * 500) * 0.015);
  $('#padala-result').text(`${Math.ceil(total)}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='padala-pera' />
<div id='padala-result'></div>
```